# Why do I fail to predict a linear equation (Y=2*x) with Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I tried to predict a linear equation (Y=2*x) with Keras, but there it failed.

With a sigmoid activation function I get rectangular predictions, with ReLu I get NaN´s.

What is the cause? How could I change the code to predict y=2*x.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time


x = np.arange(-100, 100, 0.5)
y = x*2

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.add(Dense(20) )
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

t1 = time.clock()
for i in range(40):
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=len(x), verbose=0)
    predictions = model.predict(x)
    print (i," ", np.mean(np.square(predictions - y))," t: ", time.clock()-t1)

    plt.hold(False)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'b', x, predictions, 'r--')
    plt.hold(True)
    plt.ylabel('Y / Predicted Value')
    plt.xlabel('X Value')
    plt.title([str(i)," Loss: ",np.mean(np.square(predictions - y))," t: ", str(time.clock()-t1)])
    plt.pause(0.001)
#plt.savefig("fig2.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: In fact, since `y = 2*x` is a linear transformation, all you need is a network with a single layer and a single node (no bias). This network contains a single weight parameter which should converge to `2`. Of course this could work with a more complex network as well, but it is always a good idea to use as much domain knowledge as possible when designing a network architecture. Since you know the shape of the function, this can be done easily.

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems that the default learning rate may be inappropriate at the first glance, the real problem here is that **`sigmoid` activation is inappropriate**.

Why? Because your desired output should **NOT** be bounded, but using `sigmoid` implies a bounded output. To be more precise, your last layer computes an output `y` as

```
y=\sum_i{w_i*x_i} + b
```

while `x_i` here is the output of the second last layer, which is activated by `sigmoid`, indicating that `x_i \in [0,1]`. Because of this reason, your output `y` is bounded as `y \in [-V+b,+V+b]`, where `V=|w_0|+|w_1|+...+|w_19|`, also known as the L1norm of the weight matrix, i.e. `V=L1norm(W)`.

Since the weight matrix `W` will be learned based on your training data, it is safe to conclude that your model will **NOT** be generalizable to those testing data, whose value is outside of the range `( min(x_train), max(x_train) )`.

**How to fix?**

**Thought 1**: for this simple problem, you actually don't need any nonlinearity. Simply use a linear MLP as follows.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

I tested it, and it should converge in 200 epochs with an MSE around 1e-5.

**Thought 2**: use a different activation function that does not suffer the bounded output issue, e.g. `relu` (note: `tanh` is also inappropriate for the same reason).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(20) )
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

I also test this model, and it should converge even faster with a comparable MSE.

Comment: As an addition to this already great answer, I find it usually very helpful to shuffle the training data during training, especially since here we don't even use a validation set. Just throwing this out there

Comment: Thank you! I alread tried relu on my own, because I had similar thoughts on the boundaries of sigmoid... But I tried relu with SGD as an optimizer and SGD doesn´t get a solutuion... why that? ( model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='SGD'))

Comment: @Chris This is because `SGD` uses plain vanilla gradients together with the same learning rate for all parameters in the network. Because you use unscaled data that spans orders of magnitude, the weights of the different layers will need to converge at different order of magnitude as well. But since SGD uses the same update schema for all of them this will happen very slowly. `Adam` on the other hand uses some kind of adaptive momentum and hence is much more suitable. [This video](https://youtu.be/KaR4lIdI1MQ?list=PLlJy-eBtNFt6EuMxFYRiNRS07MCWN5UIA&t=233) is a great introduction to optimizers.